# How to implement Integration test using not current Spring 4.0.7 RELEASE version

Tags: spring, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing

Welcome,

We are trying to add integration tests to our Spring project. 
Here are listed current **Maven** dependencies.

```
-Spring Version: **4.0.7 RELEASE**
-JUnit: **4.8**
```

Unit tests already exist. They are executed with: `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`

We tried to use Maven configuration to exclude IntegrationTests while executing unit tests.

```
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.class</include>
                    </includes>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Unfortunately it worked only partialy, beacuse now integration tests are not executed at all. I would be grateful if anyone could help use solving this issue.
Thank You in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add goal into your failsafe configuration. Please see below: http://maven.apache.org/components/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/usage.html